# (401) Unauthorized. When connecting to sharepoint site with App Only Authentication using PnP.Framework

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, console-application

I am trying to connect SharePoint in a console app using SharePoint App-Only Principal Authentication. I've registered the app by creating a clientId and clientSecret, grant the tenant scoped permission and trust. My permission request XML:

```
    <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">    
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />    
    </AppPermissionRequests>
```

I am using PnP.Framework for authentication but still give me an error 401 unauthorized.
My code are as follow:

```
using (var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
        {
            var web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Title);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
        };
```

The error I get is:

```
    Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:         (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That solved my problem. For new tenants, apps using an ACS app-only access token is disabled by default.  To enable, change the behavior by running  'set-spotenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false' (needs the latest SharePoint admin PowerShell).

Answer (score 0):

`AuthenticationManager.GetACSAppOnlyContext()` [should not be used anymore for new Tenants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs):

> *For new tenants, apps using an **ACS app-only** access token is disabled by default. We recommend using the Azure **AD app-only** model which is modern and more secure.*

Instead check out [Granting access via Azure AD App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) and use this:

```cs
var authManager = new AuthenticationManager("<application id>", "c:\\temp\\mycert.pfx", "<password>", "contoso.onmicrosoft.com");
using (var cc = authManager.GetContext("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/demo"))
```